# Correcting/dumping a pickling error

Tags: pickle, dill

I made a mistake while I was attempting to pickle a model. I used dill and had this wrong command:

```
with open('ml/city_model.pkl', 'rb') asfile:
```

Here you see no space between as and file, which is the error. However, I had deleted this line but it seems the system still remembers this command.  As I attempted to submit my assignment to a remote grader, it showed

```
with open('ml/city_model.pkl', 'rb') asfile:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could I erase this in any possible way? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you are editing and submitting the same files ?

Comment: Thanks. You reminded me it could be a version control problem. Now it's fixed.